JavaFx StringProperty Updated data for different objects
In a multi-instance object, each object has a StringProperty property. However, when a StringProperty property value is set in one of the instances, that value updates the StringProperty property value in the other instances
Object instance:
private StringProperty count;

public StringProperty countProperty(){
    if (count == null){
        count = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"count");
    }
    return count;
}

public String getCount() {
    return countProperty().get();
}

public void setCount(String count) {
    this.countProperty().set(count);
}

Bound attribute value：
private void setData(SessionEntity sessionEntity){
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        sessionImg.setImage(new Image(sessionEntity.getAvatar()));
        if (sessionEntity.getDeliveryMethod().equals(DeliveryMethod.GROUP)
                && sessionEntity.getLastSendMsgUserId() != null
                && !ClientContextHolder.clientContext().id().equals(sessionEntity.getLastSendMsgUserId())){
            sendUserName.setText(sessionEntity.getLastUserName() + ":");
        }else {
            sendUserName.setText("");
        }
        nameLabel.setText(sessionEntity.getName());
        timeLabel.setText("23:34");
        lastMsg.setText(sessionEntity.getLastMsg());
        sessionEntity.countProperty().bindBidirectional(isAlert.textProperty());
    });
}

Update attribute value：
private void messageCount(SessionEntity sessionEntity){
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        if (sessionEntity != null){
            String currentCount = sessionEntity.getCount();
            if (currentCount == null || currentCount.isEmpty()){
                sessionEntity.countProperty().set("1");
            }else {
                sessionEntity.setCount(String.valueOf(Long.parseLong(currentCount) + 1));
            }
        }
    });
}

Result：
enter image description here
I tried binding the label to the instance object, but it didn't work
isAlert.textProperty().bindBidirectional(sessionEntity.countProperty());


You're creating a bidirectional binding, but there's no indication you ever remove that binding. A property can have multiple bidirectional bindings at the same time (unlike a unidirectional binding). Perhaps you're accidentally linking all the properties together. Or maybe something else is going wrong. To give a definitive answer we'll need a [mre].

Change the binding to：
isAlert.textProperty().bind(sessionEntity.countProperty())
is work

Change the binding to：
isAlert.textProperty().bind(sessionEntity.countProperty()) 

is work
